# VBA Code to Produce PDF Reports

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi I am in the process of learning access and VBA. Recently created a report (`Report1`) that displays survey comments for an individual course. The criteria on this report is `[Course]`. I also created a query that has a list of courses (`Course List`) that can be looped through to generate the report for each course. I'm looking for some basic code that can link these two together and create individual pdfs for each course.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub GetCourseName()
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Course] FROM [Course List]")

rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptReport1", acViewPreview, , "Course = " & rst!Course
  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptReport1", acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\raj.jk\Documents\Course Evaluations" & rst!Course & ".pdf"

DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptReport1"
rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
strSQL = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue, and your question, with that code? Does it work?

Comment: The issue is that the code is just opening the report and not actually filling out the criteria from the query or saving anything at all. I think primarily this line of code is the issue DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewPreview, , Course = rst!Course

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `Course` is a textual value (rather than a numeric value), so you need to surround it with single quotes in the filter expression:

```
"Course = '" & rst!Course & "'"
```

or to embed double quotes:

```
"Course = """ & rst!Course & """"
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that helped one issue but the other issue is that for some reason the code is not passing the parameter to the report as I am still being prompted to enter course.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong in the design of your report. This is not an easy task to tackle, but perhaps exporting the design of the report can be a great help. Check out this statement `Application.SaveAsText acReport, "rptReport1", "C:\rptReport1_design_exported_as_text.txt"`

I tried to recreate your database. I used these instructions:

```
Private Sub CodeToProduceTextReports__01()
' create table and insert some testing values
    CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE TABLE [Course List] (CourseID autoincrement, Course varchar(50), Course_Title varchar(50), Course_Location varchar(50))"
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Course] (Course, Course_Title, Course_Location) VALUES " & _
            "('alfa', 'first Greek lettre', 'aa')"
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Course] (Course, Course_Title, Course_Location) VALUES " & _
            "('beta', 'second Greek lettre', 'bb')"
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Course] (Course, Course_Title, Course_Location) VALUES " & _
            "('gamma', 'thirth Greek lettre', 'cc')"
End Sub

Private Sub CodeToProduceTextReports__02()
' importing the design from the report from a saved version in text format
    Application.LoadFromText acReport, "rptReport1", "C:\rptReport1_design_exported_as_text.txt"
End Sub

Private Sub CodeToProduceTextReports__03()
' --03-- print the displayed data of the imported report to a text-file
' for my testings I needed to switch from PDF to TXT
    DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "rptReport1", acFormatTXT , "C:\Data Displayed By Report.txt", False, ""
End Sub

Private Sub CodeToProduceTextReports__04()
' --04-- export the design of the report to a text-file
    Application.SaveAsText acReport, "rptReport1", "C:\design of report in text format.txt"
End Sub

Private Sub CodeToProduceTextReports__05()
' --05-- routine to print a file for each course
    ...
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptReport1", acViewPreview, , "Course = '" & rst!Course & "'"
        ' for my testings I needed to switch from PDF to TXT
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptReport1", acFormatTXT, "Course Evaluations" & rst!Course & ".txt"
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptReport1"
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    ...
End Sub
```

For executing these instructions, you need the contents of the file `"C:\rptReport1_design_exported_as_text.txt"`.

```
Version =19
VersionRequired =19
Checksum =-3122728
Begin Report
    LayoutForPrint = NotDefault
    AllowDesignChanges = NotDefault
    DefaultView =0
    TabularFamily =0
    DateGrouping =1
    GrpKeepTogether =1
    PictureAlignment =2
    DatasheetGridlinesBehavior =3
    GridY =10
    Width =5669
    ItemSuffix =3
    Left =270
    Top =600
    Right =7725
    Bottom =7140
    DatasheetGridlinesColor =12632256
    RecSrcDt = Begin
        0x8d11b150f50de540
    End
    GUID = Begin
        0xebeaeb4b353b1e41965fcce57dee6850
    End
    NameMap = Begin
        0x0acc0e5500000000b21f4d48d7501c47975fad457306950f0000000006bb61eb ,
        0x3f0ee540000000000000000043006f00750072007300650020004c0069007300 ,
        0x7400000000000000a1f51f8cd9d88f40b7d811fdc68024a207000000b21f4d48 ,
        0xd7501c47975fad457306950f43006f00750072007300650000000000000030e5 ,
        0x8a48064ac944ba5f2d69ec0cfe2507000000b21f4d48d7501c47975fad457306 ,
        0x950f43006f0075007200730065005f005400690074006c006500000000000000 ,
        0x3f6cd73810d7ed4dacc51df5fba38c4a07000000b21f4d48d7501c47975fad45 ,
        0x7306950f43006f0075007200730065005f004c006f0063006100740069006f00 ,
        0x6e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c00000002000000 ,
        0x0000000000000000000000000000
    End
    RecordSource ="Course List"
    DatasheetFontName ="Arial Narrow"
    PrtMip = Begin
        0xae050000ae050000ae050000ae0500000000000025160000a506000001000000 ,
        0x010000006801000000000000a10700000100000001000000
    End
    PrtDevMode = Begin
        0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
        0x010400049c009000032f000002000900000000006400010001002c0101000100 ,
        0x2c01010000004c65747465720000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
        0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
        0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007769646d ,
        0x10000000010000000000000000000000fe00000001000000000000002c010000 ,
        0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
        0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
        0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
        0x000000000000000000000000
    End
    PrtDevNames = Begin
        0x080036005d000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
        0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
        0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d6963 ,
        0x726f736f667420446f63756d656e7420496d6167696e67205772697465722050 ,
        0x6f72743a00
    End
    Begin
        Begin Label
            BackStyle =0
            TextFontFamily =2
            FontName ="Arial"
        End
        Begin TextBox
            FELineBreak = NotDefault
            OldBorderStyle =0
            TextFontFamily =2
            Width =1701
            LabelX =-1701
            FontName ="Arial"
        End
        Begin Section
            KeepTogether = NotDefault
            Height =1701
            Name ="Details"
            GUID = Begin
                0xbbf704242af93b45b77934d4cf2c2e95
            End
            Begin
                Begin TextBox
                    IMESentenceMode =3
                    Left =1870
                    Top =113
                    Name ="Course"
                    ControlSource ="Course"
                    GUID = Begin
                        0xc8704b4483a48440b68813fa30cc9d70
                    End
                    Begin
                        Begin Label
                            Left =169
                            Top =113
                            Width =630
                            Height =225
                            Name ="Bijschrift0"
                            Caption ="Course:"
                            GUID = Begin
                                0xb620b2a6a8332d42a52b1dc58425b1be
                            End
                        End
                    End
                End
                Begin TextBox
                    IMESentenceMode =3
                    Left =2097
                    Top =453
                    TabIndex =1
                    Name ="Course_Title"
                    ControlSource ="Course_Title"
                    GUID = Begin
                        0xd33ee5134f828846ad63db31ed83c4e4
                    End
                    Begin
                        Begin Label
                            Left =396
                            Top =453
                            Width =1005
                            Height =225
                            Name ="Bijschrift1"
                            Caption ="Course_Title:"
                            GUID = Begin
                                0x44b12ea59ae514488e333d8451fbf68a
                            End
                        End
                    End
                End
                Begin TextBox
                    IMESentenceMode =3
                    Left =2381
                    Top =850
                    TabIndex =2
                    Name ="Course_Location"
                    ControlSource ="Course_Location"
                    GUID = Begin
                        0x139fdfe9aad7034aa7ad2f137e63e486
                    End
                    Begin
                        Begin Label
                            Left =680
                            Top =850
                            Width =1290
                            Height =225
                            Name ="Bijschrift2"
                            Caption ="Course_Location:"
                            GUID = Begin
                                0x8f36ef586867bb4faf9cbc80efd0a570
                            End
                        End
                    End
                End
            End
        End
    End
End
```